# Search within text file and execute

Tags: vb.net, search, text

I'm really a beginner on VB so if you can help me I'd be grateful. My issue is really simple. I have a plain .txt file (lets say test.txt) I'd like to search inside on a specific line (lets say line 22) on two specific characters (lets say characters 5 and 6). If the number found is larger than 18 then execute a .bat file. If not do nothing.

I'd appreciate some help !

Answer (score 0):

This should provide you some examples that you will need:

```
    Public Sub FindCode()

    Dim tempLines As List(Of String)
    Dim position As Int32


    tempLines = ReadFileLines("c:\filename.txt")

    If tempLines Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("file not read")
        Return
    End If

    If tempLines.Count < 22 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Line 22 does not exist")
        Return
    End If

    'position of line is one less than we are lookign for since List(Of T) is zero based
    position = 22 - 1

    If tempLines(position).Length < 6 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Line 22 does not have 6 characters")
        Return
    End If

    If IsNumeric(tempLines(position).Substring(4, 2)) = False Then
        'characters 5 and 6 (zero based (4) for 2 characters)
        MessageBox.Show("characters 5-6 are not numeric")
    End If

    If CInt(tempLines(position).Substring(4, 2)) <= 18 Then
        MessageBox.Show("characters 5-6 are less than or equal to 18")
        Return
    End If

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\batchfile.bat")


End Sub

Public Function ReadFileLines(p_fileName As String) As List(Of String)
    If System.IO.File.Exists(p_fileName) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("File does not exist")
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Return System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(p_fileName).ToList()

End Function
```

Comment: wow very thanks ! so just to understand it, if lets say it was not characters 5 and 6 and it was lets say characters 15 and 16 i would just put Substring(14, 2)) right?

Comment: Correct.  Remember to mark this as your answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I am getting Line 2 Char 15 Expected end of statement :(
Code 800A0401

Comment: Apologies but i am trying it on VBS maybe its different?

Comment: Yes VB Script is different than VB.NET. VBS will require a totally different approach.